# How to programmatically associate a layer with a python init method from external file?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.18

I know it is possible to associate a layer with a custom UI for editing feature attributes using the QGIS interface by using python:

```
vectorLayer1.setEditForm('/home/me/uifile.ui')
```

And I found this to associate the vector layer with python init method:

```
vectorLayer1.setEditFormInit('moduleName.functionName')
```

But this only allowed when the module (python file) located in the same directory as my project. Is there any ways to load from external file?

Comment: between, i'm using QGIS 2.18

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I found a way to avoid it. I just set the right external file to my Style (.qml) and I do use `Layer.setEditForm()` and `Layer.setEditFormInit()` and it works perfectly!

Comment: Cy T does anything worked out for you ? if yes can you accept the answer or share your experience ? it will be valuable for other. Thanks.